# Why does this javascript array not pass to php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I know this has been asked before but I can't get any solutions to work. I have an js array that looks like this in the console:-

```
[]
  0:Object
    stock:27
    createdtime:"2016-04-08T04:00:00+0000"
    id:"693852404037393999"
    units:438
  1:Object
    stock:17
    createdtime:"2016-04-04T07:00:00+0000"
    id:"341884943444989396"
    units:267
```

The code to create this array looks like this:-

```
  var allstock = {
      pdata: []
  };

        allstock.pdata.push({
            "stock" : response.stock,
            "createdtime" : response.createdtime,
            "id" : response.id,
            "units" : response.units
          });
```

I then send it to php via ajax like this:-

```
                //ADD STOCK DETAIL TO DB
    var mydata = 'stockarray='+ JSON.stringify(allstock.pdata);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'stocktodb.php',
            data: mydata,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#showarraydata').html(data);

                }
            });
```

In my stocktodb.php file I have this:

```
<?php

$myarray = $_POST['stockarray'];
$mydata = json_decode($myarray,true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($mydata);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

But when this returned / echoed, I only get this on the screen:-

```
Array
(
)
```

I think the array is not even getting to POST or there is something wrong with the array (although it validates with json lint). Maybe something to do with stringify and the fact that my array only shows [] in the console and then objects below that?

I'm at a loss and have tried many different things but no joy. Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: anyone please explain why my question has been downvoted please?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your ajax code like below.

```
//ADD STOCK DETAIL TO DB 
$.ajax({ 
  type: "POST", 
  url: 'stocktodb.php', 
  data: {stockarray : JSON.stringify(allstock.pdata)}, 
  success: function(data) { 
    $('#showarraydata').html(data); 
  } 
});
```

---

Comment: Not sure why the question has been downvoted :-( Anyhow, thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. When I console log JSON.stringify(allstock.pdata) it is empty, when I console.log allstock.pdata I get the full array. I think it may be because the array should be an object but can't be suer and don't know how to change it?

Comment: @JonathanLyon not sure. Can you try without JSON.stringify?

Comment: it's strange - it still shows an empty array when I console it with or without strinify - "stockarray=". I think it has to do with the array itself. It will show data in the console but the first element is [] then 0:Object,1:Object,2:Object etc. So I think it has to do with the initial. opening [] that is suggesting it's an empty array when it's not maybe?

Comment: @JonathanLyon your code is working for me. I just created one sample fiddle for your reference - https://jsfiddle.net/v4nrok5v/ Please check your browser console. In my console, I can see the elements

Comment: Thanks, the array is not the issue, I see the elements as well. However,  when I try to send the array via ajax it doesn't pass anything. If I add data: {stockarray : JSON.stringify(allstock)}, and try and console.log this I get nothing

Comment: @JonathanLyon Ok. please check in browser developer tool network tab where we can see the what are the values are passing while ajax request is processing. So if it is passing, something we have to do with your php script side. Please take a look once.

Comment: Add this to the PHP `file_put_contents('debug.txt', print_r($_POST,1));` then look at the file to see what is actually being passed in $_POST